# Ricoh SP 310dn not working with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, ubuntu-drivers

My Ricoh SP 310dn was smoothly working in Ubuntu 16.04, after up-gradation to Ubuntu 18.04 the printer is not working. The same ppd file used for installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and asked Ricoh Technical Support for a workaround. I was told that their driver file `RICOH SP 310SFN.ppd` would not work with distros later than 16.x.

Instead I was asked to use this `generic` driver in the CUPS+Gutenprint stable:

`Generic PCL 6 Printer wide margin - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3`

I tried it and it works. You might need to set up the printer using `localhost:631` on a web browser.

FWIW, my setup is as follows:

```
Printer Model: Ricoh SP 310DN
Printer Driver: Generic PCL 6 Printer wide margin - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3
Printer Driver File: STP02101.ppd
Gutenprint Version: 5.3.3
Linux Kernel Release: 5.3.7-2-MANJARO
DISTRIB_ID=ManjaroLinux
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.1.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Juhraya
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```

I hope this helps.